# No data return after calling the stored procedures with multiple cursors in it

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I have a stored procedures with the following code. The reason i use cursor is to join table which something will return NULL value and cause the record to be disappear. By using this method, I am able to get all data without losing any.

The only problem now is that when i try to call the stored precedures, it return 
Error Code : 1329
No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

but when i do a manual select * from TMOMain, the table is created and there is data in it but no data from SignUpCur and UnSubCur mean it was not updated.

1st time using mysql stored procedures so there might be something i miss out.

My Code

```
ROOT:BEGIN

DECLARE pTotal,pShortCode,pSignUp,pUnSub,pJunk,pT INT;
DECLARE pTc NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE SignTotal,UnSubTotal, JunkTotal INT;
DECLARE pSignTotal,pSignTeamID,pUnSubTotal,pUnSubT,pSignUpS,pUnSubS INT; 
DECLARE pSignTeam,pUnSubTeam NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;

DECLARE MoMainCur CURSOR FOR
SELECT COUNT(*) AS GrandTotal,pShort,(CASE WHEN r= 1 THEN 'A'
WHEN r= 2 THEN 'B' WHEN r= 3 THEN 'C' ELSE 'UV' END) AS Team,recvTeamID
FROM tbli
INNER JOIN tblK ON keywordid = rkey
WHERE recvDate >='2011-11-15'  AND recvDate < '2011-11-16' 
GROUP BY pShort,Team,recvTeamID;

DECLARE SignUpCur CURSOR FOR
SELECT COUNT(*) AS SignUp,(CASE WHEN r= 1 THEN 'A'
WHEN r= 2 THEN 'B' WHEN r= 3 THEN 'C' ELSE 'UV' END) AS Team,
recvTeamID,pShort
FROM tbli INNER JOIN tbl_user ON recvphone = userphone
INNER JOIN tblK ON keywordid = userpublicstatus
WHERE userdatejoined >='2011-11-15' AND userdatejoined < '2011-11-16'
AND recvdate >='2011-11-15' AND recvdate < '2011-11-16'
GROUP BY Team,recvTeamID,pShort;

DECLARE UnSubCur CURSOR FOR
SELECT COUNT(*) AS UnSub,(CASE WHEN r= 1 THEN 'A'
WHEN r= 2 THEN 'B' WHEN r= 3 THEN 'C' ELSE 'UV' END) AS Team,
recvTeamID,pShort
FROM tbliINNER JOIN tbl_user ON recvphone = userphone 
INNER JOIN tblK ON keywordid = userpublicstatus 
WHERE userdateExpire >='2011-11-15' AND userdateExpire <'2011-11-16'
AND recvdate >='2011-11-15' AND recvdate < '2011-11-16'
GROUP BY Team,recvTeamID,pShort;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TMoMain`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMOMain
(GrandTotal INT,ShortCode INT,Team NVARCHAR(10),SignUp INT,UnSub INT, Junk INT, TeamID INT);    

OPEN MoMainCur;
-- Main Table
read_loop:LOOP
FETCH MoMainCur INTO pTotal,pShortCode,pTc,pT;

INSERT INTO TMOMain
VALUES
(pTotal,pShortcode,pTc,0,0,0,pT);   
END LOOP read_loop;

CLOSE MoMainCur;

-- Insert Signup Details into Main Table
OPEN SignUpCur;

SignUp_Loop:LOOP
FETCH SignUpCur INTO pSignTotal,pSignTeam,pSignTeamID,pSignUpS;

UPDATE TMOMain 
SET SignUp = pSignTotal
WHERE Team = pSignTeam AND Shortcode =pSignUpS;

END LOOP SignUp_Loop;       

CLOSE SignUpCur;

-- Insert UnSub Details into Main Table
OPEN UnSubCur;

UnSub_Loop:LOOP
FETCH UnSubCur INTO pUnSubTotal,pUnSubTeam,pUnSubT,pUnSubS;

UPDATE TMOMain 
SET UnSub = pSignTotal
WHERE Team = pUnSubTeam AND pShort = pUnSubShortCode;

END LOOP UnSub_Loop;        

CLOSE UnSubCur;

SELECT * FROM TMOMain;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out:

Add this declaration once (at the top):

```
DECLARE curIsDone INT DEFAULT FALSE;
```

Then after you declare your cursor add this:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET curIsDone = TRUE;
```

After your `FETCH` commands and before the actions you intend to perform:

```
IF curIsDone THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
```